# Is my ablution still valid?

Tags: wudu, taharah, muslim-practices

I recently shifted to European country and for my surprise there are no bidet or Muslim showers, so I was told that people use toilet paper. Given that, does one ablution break or does one have to do it again (sometimes your out of house). Is there any fatwa for it about cleanness and ablution?

Answer (score 2):

Islamic way to clean yourself after relieving from nature call is that water is best in that case. But in case of necessity, where there is no water available, then you ca use toilet paper (as suggested by scholars of islam) as cleaning one self with stone too is allowed (after passing stool or urine). So toilet paper should not be an issue.

For proper details of this ruling,you can goto this link: http://islamqa.info/en/59928

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in Quran and reliable hadiths that indicates the breaking of Wudhu if one doesn't properly cleanse himself after defecating.  You do your best to clean yourself.

You can even wet a whole bunch of toilet paper and keeping them in the bathroom while you go, and use them when you finish.

You can carry an empty water bottle or similar things around with you. No effort is wasted.

Try to find different ways to doing things.  Don't allow yourself to be limited.

But it doesn't break wudhu if you find out you didn't clean yourself properly.